# JMF how to find the required DLL's

Tags: jmf

I am developing a small app that captures photos from the web cam.I developed this app using NetBeans 7.0 .App worked fine when i runned through NetBeans.But when executed outside NetBeans in the dist folder which contains the executable jar file of the app it couldn't detect the webcam.I placed the necessary libraries (jmf.jar) in the lib folder.Still the problem exists.As I heard i have to place some dll's can anybody ans elaboratly? Thanks in advance

Comment: can you share the error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

You must include the ***jmf.properties*** file in the same directory as your executable jar file.

You will find the ***jmf.properties*** file in the lib folder of your jmf installation. For me it was: `C:\Program Files\JMF2.1.1e\lib\jmf.properties`.

Comment: +1 -- From @Hien (who hasn't got comment rep yet), "Thanks kidhuvig." "This worked for me"(paraphrased).